# Java Bukkit/Spigot - Block Specified Commands

Tags: java, plugins, server, minecraft, bukkit

i'm trying to make a plugin, it must block a specified commands setted by config. i've maked this but it doesn't block any command.

Code:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGHEST)
  public void onPreprocess(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event)
  {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    String command = event.getMessage();
    List<String> bCmds = this.plugin.cfg.getStringList("blocked-commands");

    for (String bCmd : bCmds) 
    {
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase(bCmd))
        {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
  }
```

Config:

```
blocked-commands:
- /pl
- /op
- /sp
- /gravityblock
```

PS: I've tried to use:

```
String command = event.getMessage().subString(1);
```

Thanks for Help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Registered events? implemented listner?

Also your code will not work with additional arguments in the command.
If it contains spaces, split it with " " and get the first element to just get the command

if (cmd.contains(" ")) cmd = cmd.split(" ")[0];

Comment: Omg... i don't have registered the Event xDDDD Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Bukkit's wiiki](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference), the priorities are called in the following order:

- EventPriority.LOWEST
- EventPriority.LOW
- EventPriority.NORMAL
- EventPriority.HIGH
- EventPriority.HIGHEST
- EventPriority.MONITOR

Maybe you could try to use the Lowest priority, so the event gets cancelled before the command is handled.

I also believe that the command might have arguments, so it might not be equal to the string provided, you should also try

```
String command = event.getMessage();


if (command.toLowerCase().startsWith("/command") ) {
    //cancel
}
```